# How to initialize server-side components in NextJs App router

Tags: next.js, next.js13, tsyringe

Is there any way in NextJS App router to initialize things apart from calling initialization routines at the top of every page and every layouts?

I am aware of `instrumentation.ts`, but it runs in a separate Node execution context and is run only once, so everything initialized in there is not accessible in other parts of the app (like pages and layouts). Initializing DI containers such as `tsyringe` in `instrumentation.ts` and accessing them in other parts of the app does not work.